# How to connect elasticsearch to apache spark streaming or storm?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, apache-storm, spark-streaming

We are building a real-time big data tool with open source tools. Our main goal is to supervise and analyze a network by getting logs from a kafka server in real-time. We saw in tutorials that we have to divide our tool in two sections: Analytic and Supervision as shown below.

[image]

For the supervision section we chose the solution Elasticsearch and Logstash.

Regarding the section analytic, my team and I are comparing Apache Storm Streaming and Apache Storm in order to use it with Elasticsearch. Despite the fact that Apache Storm is a true real-time data processing tool and faster than Apache Spark Streaming, it does not provide machine learning libraries like with Apache Spark. That's why we are thinking to choose Apache Spark. The elastic website indicates that it exists a connector ES-Hadoop to connect a Elasticsearch database to a Hadoop ecosystem. We can see that in the below figure.
[image]

However, We are a little bit confused with this picture because there is only spark SQL and not all the spark frameworks (MLlib, Spark Streaming..). We did some assumptions and we came out with two final possible architectures. We only wanted to know if there are technically correct and if we are not in the wrong direction.

With Apache Spark streaming:
[image]

With Apache Storm:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your architectural diagrams are ok. Keep on mind that spark streaming will not work in this scenario. Es-hadoop provides you with easy access apis to get and put data from and into elastic. Its also provides the methods to get the data inro the spark framework (RDD) or data frames inthe case of spark sql. Once the data is in the framework, all ml libraries can be applied to the data for ml or analytics generation.  Elastic is not capable of streaming data so spark streaming in the strict sense is not possible. So in the diagram, the arrow to hdfs optional and then to spark streaming can be removed and the arrow juat pointa to hdfs. My concern, however, would be running mllib algos on the data in realtime and expect realtime performance. Typical use case might be do modwl generation off line and use the model in realtime for analysis.

Comment: thank you Ramdev. Regarding you concern, I saw that K-meaning and linear regression algorithms in spark can be use in real-time. Futhermore, I did not really well understand the interest of spark sql. an you explain me that ?

Comment: The availability of Spark SQL is so that the data, once in Spark dataframe, can be queried using simple SQL like statements.  Its available. However if your workflow does not really involve treating the data in a relational data sense, Spark SQL is not the tool you would use. Spark SQL is just one more way of accessing the Elastic data (since most people are familiar with using RDBMS' for data manipulation).